# PHP MySQL Pagination Issue -- additional pages display all rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently searching my db and displaying results 5 per page and then I am intending to provide the user with links to the additional pages.

When i run this code it limits my initial query to the 5 records but then when I click on the links for the additional pages it is ignoring my sql query parameters and retuning all rows in the database.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="results.css">
</head>
<img src="http://meritscholarshiplist.com/wordpress/wp- content/uploads/2015/12/searchhead.png" alt="" width="100%" style="padding-top:0px;"/>
<a href="http://meritscholarshiplist.com/wordpress/search-2#searcht|0"><-Search Again</a>
</html>
<?php 
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$school = $_POST['school'];
$num_rec_per_page=5;
mysql_connect('', '', '');
mysql_select_db('');

if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page  = $_GET["page"];
} else {
    $page=1;
}

;
$start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `school` LIKE '%$school%' LIMIT    $start_from, $num_rec_per_page";
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
//run the query
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result)) {
    echo "<div class='list' style='width:1750px; margin:0 auto;'>";
    echo "<form action='singleview.php' method='post' target='_new$array[0]'><table id='scholarship' style='float:left;' align='center'><thead><th class='head' colspan='3' style='text-align:center;'>$array[2]<br><br>$array[5]<br><br>$array[3]<br><br><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$array[0]'><input type='submit'  value='View More Details'><br>(Will Open in a New Tab)</th></thead>";
    echo "</form></table></div> ";
}

;
?>
<?php
$school = $_POST['school'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `school` LIKE '%$school%'";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
//run the query
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
//count number of records
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page);
echo "<a href='search.php?page=1'>".'|<'."</a> ";
// Goto 1st page  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='search.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
}

;
echo "<a href='search.php?page=$total_pages'>".'>|'."</a> ";
// Goto last page
echo "<br>Your Search Returned $total_records Results";
?>
```

Comment: since  $num_rec_per_page is hard coded i dont see how what you describe is possible. `echo $sql;` is limit set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are clicking on the page number, your browser is making a `GET` request without the value of `school`. You can first add `school` to the request like

```
echo "<a href='search.php?page=1&school=".urlencode($school)."'>".'|<'."</a> ";
// Goto 1st page  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='search.php?school=".urlencode($school)."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
}
```

and make sure you can get the value of `school` from both `GET` and `POST`:

```
$school = $_REQUEST['school']; // instead of $_POST['school']
```